# httpwebrequest and base64 data chunks

Tags: c#, string, winforms, base64, httpwebrequest

I have a requirement where I have to upload large (over 200mb) attachments to a server as base64 strings using the HttpWebRequest class.

My understanding is that if we base64 encode a 200mb file at once (without doing as chunks) it could exceed the practical limit of the size a string.

Has anybody come across a situation where you have base64 encoded a string as chunks and uploaded as chunks too ?

note - I already can base64 encode a large file as chunks and write to a file as chunks.

Thanks

Comment: Send data as raw bytes. Do not encode it to base64. Why u need base64?

Comment: Thanks, the server is not in my control and uses multipart/mixed content type and request the attachments to be sent base64 encoded.

Comment: That's not your fault my friend. You can not send 200 MB bytedata as base64 :( I'd contact the server if i were you. That's completely wrong